# Reading strings from a file and creating Adjacency lists for Graphs

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-list

Newbie here!!. For my project, I have to read data as string from a file and create a graph for BFS, with adjacency list.I'm reading each line from the file and taking the first string as key and next string as it neighbor. But I can't understand, why I get null pointer exception.Please take a look at my code. My file looks like this

city.txt

```
city1  city2   10
city1  city3   15
city2  city1   5
city2  city3   6 
city2  city4   22
city2  city5   1
city3  city4   9
city3  city5   16
city4  city1   4
city4  city2   8
city5  city2   1
city5  city3   13
```

And my Graph.java file is

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {

    Map<String, LinkedList<String>> adj;

    public Graph() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Graph(String[] nodes) 
    {
       adj = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();
       for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) 
       {
          adj.put(nodes[i], new LinkedList<String>());
       }
    }

    public void addNeighbor(String v1,String v2) {
       adj.get(v1).add(v2);
    }

    public List<String> getNeighbors(String v) {
       return adj.get(v);
    }

    public void getKeyValuePairs()
    {
        Iterator iterator = adj.keySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
           String key = iterator.next().toString();
           LinkedList<String> value = adj.get(key); 
           System.out.println(key + " " + value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("city.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String [] nodes = new String[tokens.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
           nodes[i] = tokens[i];
        }

        Graph g = new Graph(nodes);
        String var_1 = tokens[0];
        String var_2 = tokens[1];
        //String var_3 = tokens[2];



        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
        {

           tokens = line.split("\\s+");
           nodes = new String[tokens.length];
           for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
              nodes[i] = tokens[i];
           }

           var_1 = tokens[0];
           var_2 = tokens[1];
           //String var_3 = tokens[2];

           g.addNeighbor(var_1, var_2);

        }
        g.getKeyValuePairs();
        br.close();
     }

  }
```

I am getting a null pointer exception error in the line g.addNeighbor(var_1, var_2) how do I solve the problem. Can somebody suggest some solution for this.

EDIT..

I also using `getKeyValuePairs()` to view the adjacency list but I'm getting some weird output. Any possible suggestion why this happens?

output:

```
 [city2]
city1 [city2, city2]
city2 [city2, city2, city2, city2]
city3 [city2, city2]
city4 [city2, city2]
city5 [city2, city2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your HashMap adj doesn't include the vertex var_1. You only add vertices of the first line to the graph.

Edit: Below is a working sample:

```
public class Graph
{
    Map<String, LinkedList<String>> adj;

    public Graph() {
        adj = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();
    }

    public void addNode(String node) 
    {
        adj.putIfAbsent(node, new LinkedList<String>());
    }

    public void addNeighbor(String v1,String v2) {
       adj.get(v1).add(v2);
    }

    public List<String> getNeighbors(String v) {
       return adj.get(v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("city.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        String [] tokens;

        Graph g = new Graph();
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
        {
           tokens = line.split("\\s+");
           g.addNode( tokens[0]);
           g.addNode( tokens[1]);
           g.addNeighbor( tokens[0], tokens[1]);
        }
        br.close();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add to your `Map`. Here's your code with the bugfix that adds to the map:

```
if(adj.get(v1) == null) {
   adj.put(v1, new LinkedList<String>());
}
```

Complete code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    private Map<String, LinkedList<String>> adj;

    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Main(String[] nodes)
    {
        adj =new HashMap<String, LinkedList<String>>();
        System.out.println("nodes" + nodes.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i)
        {
            adj.put(nodes[i], new LinkedList<String>());
        }
    }

    public void addNeighbor(String v1,String v2) {
        if(adj.get(v1) == null) {
            adj.put(v1, new LinkedList<String>());
        }
        adj.get(v1).add(v2);
    }

    public List<String> getNeighbors(String v) {
        return adj.get(v);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File("city.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();
        String [] tokens = line.split("\\s+");
        String [] nodes = new String[tokens.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
            nodes[i] = tokens[i];
        }

        Main g = new Main(nodes);
        String var_1 = tokens[0];
        String var_2 = tokens[1];
        //String var_3 = tokens[2];

        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null )
        {
            System.out.println(" test " + line);
            tokens = line.split("\\s+");
            nodes = new String[tokens.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i) {
                nodes[i] = tokens[i];
            }
            var_1 = tokens[0];
            var_2 = tokens[1];
            g.addNeighbor(var_1, var_2);

        }
        br.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I have made an edit for the question can you provide suggestion why the output is not correct.

Comment: Solved it... I have comment the var_2 variable in while loop.